# Separate First Name/Last Name fields in Exp:resso Store Billing Name field?

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to store separate first / last name fields in the Exp:resso store billing name field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom order field for this (although it won't then automatically follow the "shipping same as billing" setting, so you would need to implement that using javascript).

There is also an extension on Devot:ee which does this: [Store: Firstname/Lastname](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-firstname-lastname)

I have not used the extension, but if anyone has perhaps they could post their experience using it here.

Comment: The "Store: Firstname/Lastname" extension uses custom order fields (currently hard-coded, but eventually you'll be able to specify which ones via CP) to store the firstname and lastname values separately, and then concatenates them into Store's native fields. I also have plans to make this work with both Shipping AND Billing addresses. Feel free to send code/pull-requests via the Git repo to help me speed this along.